# Preloader в nw.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, web-apps

Приветствую всех.

Юзаю [nw.js](http://nwjs.io/) и возник вопрос, реально ли во время открытия своего `приложения` показать какую-то `анимацию` (например, как это сделано в приложениях от adobe) и скрыть её как только приложение `до грузит` нужные ресурсы и захочет `открыться`?

Искал в оф. доках, не нашел, может я что-то упустил ?!

*Заранее спасибо!*